# Cannot put image into header html

Tags: html, css

I have  a problem with inserting an image into my project. When i run the project it only shows a broken image icon. I've tried putting a different image but it's the same. I've also tried inserting the whole path into src, tried using

```
header{

background-image: url("../project/picture.jpg");

}
```

and

```
<header id="header=background">
        <div class="logo"></div>
    </header>

#header-background{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: url(picture.JPG);
}
```

While inserting

```
<img src="picture.jpg" alt="where is the image">
```

It returns the text.

Answer (score 1):

You have used wrong name in header ID, you have to use `header-background` instead of `header=background`. Example:

```
#header-background{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: url(picture.JPG);
}
<header id="header-background">
    <div class="logo"></div>
</header>
```

Or you can also use below code, but make sure that there is something inside `<div>`.

```
header
{
    background-image: url("picture.jpg");
}
<header id="header-background">
    <div class="logo">Hello</div>
</header>
```

Comment: I've tried to do it both ways, but it is not showing the picture, only the text i've put between <div>.

Comment: May be you have placed the picture in wrong folder or you have given wrong url. Make sure that it is inside same folder with the html file.

Comment: I've thought so too but i've put it in different folders and it's just not working. In the browser console i get "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()"